# How to get a ByteBuffer that will work with LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to call the `glTexImage2D` function using the OpenGL library. I'm using the LWJGL as the framework to use OpenGL in Java.

According to the documentation, this method accepts the following parameters:

```
public static void glTexImage2D(int target,
            int level,
            int internalformat,
            int width,
            int height,
            int border,
            int format,
            int type,
            java.nio.ByteBuffer pixels)
```

My implementation of this is below.

```
GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, 1092, 1092, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_INT, imageData);
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of remaining buffer elements is 3577392, must be at least 14309568. Because at most 14309568 elements can be returned, a buffer with at least 14309568 elements is required, regardless of actual returned element count
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.throwBufferSizeException(BufferChecks.java:162)
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBufferSize(BufferChecks.java:189)
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBuffer(BufferChecks.java:230)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.java:2855)
    at TextureLab.testTexture(TextureLab.java:100)
    at TextureLab.start(TextureLab.java:39)
    at TextureLab.main(TextureLab.java:20)
```

I've done allot of querying, and I assume my method of creating a ByteBuffer for the last parameter is what is causing the issue.

My code implementation for getting a ByteBuffer form an is as follows:

```
img = ImageIO.read(file);
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(pixels.length);
buffer.put(pixels);
buffer.flip();
buffer.rewind();
```

I've substituted the length of the buffer for the `width`*`height`*4 and even hardcoded to the number contained in the error, all to no luck. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I think the issue is in my ByteBuffer, but even that I'm not sure of.

Comment: It appears you're using GL_RGB (3 bytes per pixel) rather than GL_RGBA (4 bytes per pixel). Could this be the reason? (It's been a while since I've looked at OpenGL - so I'm sure I don't have it right, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lwjgl layer is telling you that your buffer should be at least 14309568 bytes big, but you provide only 3577392. The reason for this is that you used `GL_INT` as the *format* parameter of the `glTexImage2D` call, so each pixel is assumed to be represented by 3 *4-byte* integer values bz the GL.

You just want to use `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for typical 8 bit per channel image content, which exaclty maps to the 3577392 bytes you are currently providing.

Comment: fantastic, that was it, my format parameter was set to the wrong type, so it was always reading wrong. Thx!